# Get text inside parentheses include text with more parentheses?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a variable:

```
$str = "i do not need this datavar(i need this (also this) and this) i do not need this";
```

I have the following expression but returns only the content until the first pharenteses and I need everything until the last or second pharenteses.

```
$regex2 = '#(datavar\([^)]+\))#';
```

is there a way to have everything in the text and finish the match until the second parentheses (it can have more).

Comment: Regex doesn't do recursion. You're either going to have to manually account for every possible level of encapsulation, or implement an actual tokenizer/parser.

Comment: or you could do a `preg_replace` on all open and close parens to an xml tag and use a dom parser

Comment: what does the R stands for here: #\((([^()]+|(?R))*)\)#

Comment: the problem is that only brings the text until it encounters the first ")"

Comment: Recursion is supported in PCRE, but imagine there is a string literal and it contains unbalanced `(` or `)`. Recursion won't help then.

Comment: is there a way to retrieve until the second ) in this: [^)]  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text until the second closing parenthesis or until the last (or any **fixed** number). But **I don't know** how to use pcre to check for balance. Here is the code for second and last:

```
$str = "i do not need this datavar(i need this (also this) and this) i do not need this";
$regex2 = '#datavar\(([^)]+\)[^)]+)#'; //second )
$regex2 = '#datavar\((.+)\)#'; //last )
preg_match_all($regex2,$str, $m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

Comment: *"But you can't use pcre to check for balance."* -- sure you can, [recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html).

Comment: Edited to show that it's probably my limitation. If a better answer shows up I'll delete mine.

Comment: Great! it works I never thought it can be possible, tried and tried, regards bro!